# Word order when referring things by their names

Tags: word-order

What word order must be used when referring things like functions, vectors, roads, etc. For example, for a road or a function named "A":

- > I'm going to take ['A' road *or* road 'A'].
- > See [function 'A' *or* 'A' function].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For roads you are referring to the name of the road, The word road may be part of the name, or it may not

> I'm going to take Park Road.
>   I'm going to take Comely Lane.
>   I'm going to take the B2112.  (not B2112 road)

In a paper, the word "function" &c. precedes its name or number

> See equation (1)
>   Q2  (short for question two)
>   Figure 4.3 shows this relationship.

Comment: There are exceptions however... The word, "highway" usually comes before a numbered highway, "Highway 99" and after a named highway, "Pacific Highway."

Comment: That is true in some dialects. But  "the M25 motorway" would be the usual order (or just M25 when the context is clear)